# 特定のcocoapodsのバージョンを入れることができない

Tags: swift, ruby, xcode, cocoapods, rbenv

現状のcocoapodsのバージョンを1.11.2にしたくて、[この記事](https://qiita.com/moya_dev/items/336c9e8ee32f05e4fbdd)を参考に

```
$gem install cocoapods -v 1.11.2
```

のコマンドをターミナルで打ち込んだんですが、

```
Ignoring bigdecimal-2.0.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 2.0.0
Ignoring digest-crc-0.6.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine digest-crc --version 0.6.3
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.7 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.7
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

っとなってしまいcocoapodsをアップデートできませんでした。
おそらくrbenvが原因だと考えて、[この記事](https://qiita.com/nishina555/items/63ebd4a508a09c481150)を参考に

```
$ rbenv install 3.0.3
```

を打ち込んだんですが、

```
Downloading openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/0b7a3e5e59c34827fe0c3a74b7ec8baef302b98fa80088d7f9153aa16fa76bd1
Installing openssl-1.1.1l...
Installed openssl-1.1.1l to /Users/fujitayuusaku/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3

Downloading ruby-3.0.3.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.0/ruby-3.0.3.tar.gz
Installing ruby-3.0.3...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.1 using ruby-build 20211203)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/g8/c_ksvkx96m37bzwpng3m8tch0000gn/T/ruby-build.20211213020200.34028.OU0OiR
Results logged to /var/folders/g8/c_ksvkx96m37bzwpng3m8tch0000gn/T/ruby-build.20211213020200.34028.log

Last 10 log lines:
                                                                       ^
In file included from compile.c:40:
./vm_callinfo.h:217:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RUBY_FUNCTION_NAME_STRING'
    if (debug) rp(ci);
               ^
./internal.h:95:72: note: expanded from macro 'rp'
#define rp(obj) rb_obj_info_dump_loc((VALUE)(obj), __FILE__, __LINE__, RUBY_FUNCTION_NAME_STRING)
                                                                       ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [compile.o] Error 1
```

となってしまいどうすればいいかわかりません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

> $gem install cocoapods -v 1.11.2
> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

あなたが実行しているのは、MacOS標準のrubyのgemコマンドでしょう。
MacOS標準のrubyはroot管理者の領域にありますので、一般ユーザーに書き込み権限はありません。

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems $ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel  192 10  8  2019 2.3.0/
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  wheel  288 10 29 22:03 2.6.0/
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
解決しました

Comment: 解決した方法を記載してください。